# RubyGems, can't install JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I got way too many problems setting up a ruby development enviornment on my windows.
I already installed Ruby 1.9.3, DevKit for Ruby 1.9.3, RubyGems and Ruby on Rails. (Also the client for Heroku and Git, but I don't think these tools do matter for a solution.)
I now have several problems:
-> `bundle update` doesn't do what it should do, it always cancels because JSON isn't installed
-> same goes for `bundle install`, it cancels because JSON is missing
-> can't use `rails server` because of the missing JSON
-> if I try to use `gem install json` I'm getting the following error:

```
D:\Bibliotheken\Dokumente\RailsProjects\first_app>gem install json
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
"D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby 1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby 1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)
Gems will remain installed in D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby 1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby 1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

-> after this try I can't call `rails -v` anymore, it's putting an error to the console aswell

```
<[31mCould not find gem 'sdoc <= 0.3.20) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.<[0m
<[31mRun 'bundle install' to install missing gems.<[0m
```

And there is the joke, how can I use "bundle install" if it's not working? :(
Every help is appreciated, I'm a bloody beginner in setting up development enviorments. If you need **any** additional information, I will provide them as soon as I can get them!

Edit:
Content of gem_make.out:

```
"D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby 1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb 
D:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby 1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)
```

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 manually using the Rubyinstaller because the Railsinstaller **didn't** work for me (it nearly put the same error if I wanted to get JSON!). Then I did an update to install DevKit, and used `gem install rails` to get rails.

Zerotime

Note: English isn't my native language, don't feel bothered by mistakes :)

Comment: What's in the log? How did you install Ruby/Rails in the first place? With railsinstaller it generally goes fairly smoothly.

Comment: I edited my original post, the information you need is now included. RailsInstaller just did, eh, nothing expect throwing the same error as the manual installation does...

Comment: @Zerotime this is not an answer to your problem, but I strongly recommend creating a partition and installing a UNIX OS. It is **WORTH** it

Comment: @Zerotime I have to completely agree with Nobita. I have tried setting up rails on windows and it's more trouble that it's worth. Even running a VM with a Linux variation like Ubuntu / Fedora will get  you started quickly.

Comment: @Nobita I went for a Ubuntu partion, and got Ruby running. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Zerotime congrats! Ubuntu is great :) Now enjoy, and if you have any questions about the OS itself, you can go to http://askubuntu.com/